# Large adjacency matrix to long form

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

I have a large adjacency matrix in a pandas dataframe (~7500 rows and columns) that I am trying to turn into tall form using

Some 200,000 values are non-zero. I am using colab but it keeps crashing because of running out of RAM.

```
             A             B             C             D     ....                                                                 
A           1.0           0.0           0.0           0.0
B           0.0           1.0           1.0           0.0
C           0.0           1.0           1.0           0.0
D           0.0           0.0           0.0           1.0
:
:
```

I can write a loop to filter out the non-zero values in each row and append those to a list but is there a more pythonic way for this?

Comment: It depends on your current code and which part is crashing? Loading the DataFrame? Converting to long form? 7500x7500 is not big for a recent computer. Have you tried numpy? (`np.where(df.eq(1))`) Or simply `stack`/`melt`: `df.stack()`/`df.melt()`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, I recreated your adjacency matrix and performed the stacking, It took 4 seconds to run the entire code below on a 16GB machine.

```
import random
import numpy as np

# ----- CREATING RANDOM ADJACENCY MATRIX -----

# Create a list of possible values v1 to v7500
possible_values = [f'v{i}' for i in range(1, 7501)]

# Create 100.000 random combinations of possible values.
col1 = random.choices(possible_values, k=100000)
col2 = random.choices(possible_values, k=100000)

# This would look like this in a dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2})
# print(df.head())
#     col1   col2
# 0  v1283  v5472
# 1  v2054  v2352
# 2  v5343  v6605
# 3  v3203  v4100
# 4  v1583   v513

# Now we make a cross tab from the two columns
df = pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)

# We want all possible values as row indices and column indices
df = df.reindex(index=possible_values, columns=possible_values, fill_value=0)
# The DF is now an adjacency matrix of 7500 rows and columns

# ----- CREATING LONG FORM -----

# Creating a tall form could be done like so:
df = df.stack().rename('adj').loc[lambda x: x>0].reset_index()
print(df.head())
#   col1   col2  adj
# 0   v1   v563    1
# 1   v1   v816    1
# 2   v1  v1440    1
# 3   v1  v1628    1
# 4   v1  v1856    1
```